# spark: shuffle spill to disk always happen even there is enough memory

Tags: scala, memory, apache-spark, shuffle, emr

I ran a Spark job, and I noticed that there is always some amount of shuffle spill to disk even though there should be enough memory for the shuffle spill. Does anyone know why this is happening? Would if affect performance because of such spill to disk? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It seems like you have a skewed partition size (your largest is very large). Are you sure there is enough memory to process the largest partition? What evidence are you relying on to believe that there is? Can you make the reads more even?

Comment: This is a not well-known fact, that Spark always writes *final* shuffle data to disk. You could give spark 10x more memory, but it would still write that 207MB to disk.